# TextView com altura dinâmica

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para deixar minha `UITextView` com a altura dinâmica, algo parecido com o **WhatsApp**. Preciso que conforme o texto seja digitado a mesma aumente sozinha.

Desde já grato pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma vez que você define o *delegate* no cabeçalho da sua classe:

```
class TesteViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

Então você implementa os dois métodos abaixo, sendo que o `textViewDidChange` você irá definir uma nova altura cada vez que o texto for modificado:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    let maxHeight: CGFloat = 312.0
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    let newSize: CGSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame: CGRect = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmax(newSize.width, fixedWidth), fmin(newSize.height, maxHeight))
    textView.frame = newFrame
}
```